# Enabling Paypal Pro and Paypal Standard at the same time

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, paypal-express, paypal-pro, paypal-standard

I would like to accept Paypal pro credit card orders, and Paypal payments.

The problem is that Paypal Express which is enabled by default with Pro, redirects the customer before they complete the Magento checkout process, which on my site includes further data capture.

I have followed the points here:
[Enable Paypal Pro & Standard in Magento 1.7](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6699/enable-paypal-pro-standard-in-magento-1-7/8351#8351?newreg=98857aaf3c2249daa2b3cb86cfa47a27)

This does indeed work for the front end, unfortunately in the back end Magento shows orders as pending payment, even when they are paid. I'm guessing this is because Paypal Standard isn't actually active in the back end, anyone know how I can activate it?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to have Paypal Express Checkout button displayed in the shopping cart you can turn it off in the Basic settings of Express Checkout. This will allow to have PayPal mark available on the Payments step only along with Pro. In this case customer will be forced to fill in all the fields before get to the payment page. Also in 1.9 you have an ability to skip order review page for Express and make checkout process even more shorter. See this [link.](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/new-features-ce19-ee114)

Pro can be activated with Express only, besides Express API is better than Standard since does not rely on IPN - able to process payment and create order at the same time.